# How to copy text from text editor to tty command line

Tags: linux, debian, vim, clipboard, text

Using debian 11 GNU/linux bullseye without mouse, only keyboard.
The problem:
I have a file with a password, very long and complicated.
I need to copy it and paste when I login via ssh.
I tried to copy it in Vim with selecting it and Y (yank), but nothing helps.

Comment: Y will only move it into vim's buffer, not the clipboard.  You might have more success by using `mypwd=$( grep <part of password> <path/to/file> )` and then using `$mypwd` on the command line to `ssh`.  Do stop and think though, are you exposing a valuable password to bad actors?

Comment: oh what a complicated method=) ill try, thnx. No im just learning Linux =)

Comment: @Ehrmantraut The Linux console itself does not have a clipboard. Graphical terminal emulators do, and things like `tmux`/`screen`/`gpm` do, as well. You're doing things in a manner I would not recommend, however: if you need to log in to a SSH server with a secret you store, don't store a password. Use SSH public/private key authentication. That's exactly what it's for! "Password-based authentication" is just kind of a fallback :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller oh thanks. i get it now. im walking through the overthewire.org quest. so there is a quest that suppose me to login through ssh to first user account on that server and i must find the file with the password to another user account on the server. xD so i needed to copy the pass and paste it when logging in the next account  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot copy&paste within the Linux console because it does not have a clipboard feature.

You might save the password in a variable `$mypsw` and then pass it in command line (**unsafe and not recommended**) when connecting via SSH:

```
sshpass -p "$mypsw" ssh you@yourhost
```

The **Y** key in Vim only saves in buffers inside Vim, data can't be accessed outside the text editor.